# Embedded Array insertion in mongodb using node js query

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have problem to insert a value inside an array using `node.js` and `mongodb`

1).       MongoDb Schema

```
var userScore = new Schema({
    child: {
        quiz_level: {
            current_level: {type:Number},
            level_attempted: {
                type: Array,
                level_id: {type:Number},
                level_complete: {type:Boolean},
                level_score: {type:Number}
            }
        }
    }
});
```

2).      Node js

```
try{
    // var quiz = levelScoreQuiz.child;
    var userObj = {
        "child.quiz_level.level_attempted.level_score": req.body.score
    };
    var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);
    user.save(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err)
        } else {
            console.log("User score saved successfully");
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
} catch(err){
    console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
    return next(err);
}
```

3).   Json result
      This will shows the empty result of array insertions

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "57832f610118546713d23466",
    "child": {
        "quiz_level": {
            "level_attempted": []     //This is the empty array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: level_attempted:{type:Array, there is a typo the } is later in the code. Fix it and tell us if it works.

Comment: Also var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj); should be var user = new User(userObj); & userObj should define all properties of this user according to the schema .